# How to show console output (print,etc.) in Visual Studio in C code

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to simply do a print statement and get output in the console in Visual Studio C/C++ project. I'm coming from a background using PyCharm Py3 where you simply get all your output in the console by default, however, when I run some code in Visual Studio, the whole debugger thing goes crazy.

How do I get output in the console? Thanks.

Comment: `printf` will will write to stdout, which is often "the console": for this case to be useful, the running process needs to be 'attached to a console'. Please expand on "run some code" (eg. how code is being run) and "debugger thing goes crazy" (eg. what the actual observed result is).

Comment: Again, how would I then "see" stdout? In Python you can with ease debug programs with print statements to see the flow of your program and just for fun. How would I do this in Visual Studio with C?

Comment: "How to do": `printf` for C and `cout` for C++. Read above for why those methods, which write to stdout normally, "might not be working" and how to improve the question's clarity.

Comment: Search for what you're looking for: ["visual c++ debugger stdout"](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+c%2B%2B+debugger+stdout)

Comment: Trust me, all those links are purple lol. Crazy how such a simple thing isn't implemented.

Comment: use outputdebugstring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa?redirectedfrom=MSDN